# Why when I web scraping a price from web page I get a ? with python?

Tags: python, web-scraping

I just created my first tutorial file for webscraping a price from a web page. I did the following

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib import parse

url = 'https://www.wavemotion.gr/el/shop/smartphone-accessories/easy-one-touch-wireless-fast-charging-mount'
#download the URL and extract the content to the variable html 

request = urllib.request.Request(url)
html = urllib.request.urlopen(request).read()

#pass the HTML to Beautifulsoup.
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')

#get the HTML
main_table = soup.find("div",attrs={'class':'single-product__price'})

price = main_table.find('span',attrs={'class':'woocommerce-Price-amount amount'}).text

print(price)
```

Why I get the price as a question 54,95?

Is it normal?

Comment: Is the question mark inside a diamond? If so, this represents a character which cannot be rendered by your current encoding.

Comment: no it is just 54,95? The page displays 54,95€ but € is in different span class

Comment: It's supposed to be the Euro symbol.  But your terminal can't display it, so it shows a question mark instead.

Comment: From the page you are scraping, I see a euro symbol after the price. I think the ? means that your `print()` call can't properly render this character.

Comment: How can I force my terminal to display that character ? the terminal is in Greek

Answer (score 2):

I just changed the font of terminal to lucida.. and euro sign is displayed.. thank you!